# Python: why global variable act as local variable in method?

Tags: python

I know it is a basic question but i don't know reason of this question. I am confused a bit, why global variable is act as local variable in `test` method.

```
x=1
def test():
    print x
    x=2
    print x

print x
test()
print x
```

It is giving the exception which is like this.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Anyone let me know why it is giving this error.

Thanks

Comment: For the love of all that is good, ***please*** take the two seconds to *search* before asking such a basic question. [Google gives many good results](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+global).

Comment: "but i don't know reason of this question". The reason that your asking this question is because you want an answer to it.

Comment: I know i can search but i didn't get my solution. i m  asking only if x=1 is a global variable then why i am getting exception and why i use `global x` term for x in method. already x is global variable.

Comment: @AshishJain as the linked question says, doing `x =` anywhere in a function makes `x` be a local.

Comment: It means, In function if i use any global variable then this function will treat as local variable until we define x as `global`. Is it correct @Eevee.

Comment: @Eevee Please confirm my statement.

Comment: @AshishJain You can [confirm it on your own](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements): "If the name [to be assigned to] does not occur in a `global` statement in the current code block: the name is bound to the object in the current local namespace." In short, if you do `x = ...`, `x += ...` or whatever in a function, `x` is local unless you bind it to the global name `x` with `global x`.

Comment: you can read from a global `x` all you like, but as soon as you say `x =` in a function, `x` is defined as a local and shadows the global.